# how to retrieve primary key of the checked rows from gridview

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g

Can you please tell me how to retrieve the primary keys of the checked rows in a grid-view? I don't want to display that value or something, just use it to modify that particular row(delete, change column values etc.)
I'm using Oracle 10g at the back end.
Thanks.

Comment: you need to write code to achieve what you want... i suggest you start by writing some code... and ask questions later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataKeys` of gridview
Details:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
    DataKeyNames="emp_id">
```

The `DataKeyNames` put your primary keys value in this field.

Details link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23833/DataKeyNames

Comment: kindly mark my answer if it helped you. by clicking tick mark on the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Aspx.Page...

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
    DataKeyNames="emp_id">
```

In Cs.Page,
In Click event.

```
for(int i=0;i<gv.rows.count;i++)
{
    GridviewRow row=gv.rows[i];
    cheakbox c1=(Cheakbox)row.FindControl("chkId");
    if(c1.cheaked)
    {
         int id=Convert.toInt32(gv.Datakeys[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ProductId" AllowPaging="True" 
        BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" 
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" Width="603px">
  </asp:GridView>
```

now in your code behind for example for update

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int productid=int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
}
```